# Leaflet: remove previous layer and add new click layer when zoom is same

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i have a click function for the data in the sidebar called 'zoomMarker'. when one of the data in the sidebar, it will panTo and show the marker. its working already but whenever i have zoom that is equal to maxzoom, the previous marker is not removing but its overlapping.

i need to remove the previous layer when i click another data in the sidebar. is there other way to remove the previous layer?

```
var maxZoom = findMapNo(no).map.setZoom(11);
var Oldzoom = findMapNo(no).map.getZoom();
marker = L.marker(latLng, {icon: customIcon}).bindTooltip(tooltp).addTo(groupMarker);

if(Oldzoom == maxZoom._zoom){
            markerChecker = 0;
            if(findMapNo(no).map.hasLayer(marker)){
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(marker);
            }
            console.log("add");
            findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
            findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(marker);
            findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
            findMapNo(no).map.openPopup(popup);
        }
```

Comment: You can call `map.clearLayers()` and delete all layers

Comment: Looks like `findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(marker);` is adding the layer after you remove it.

Comment: @FalkeDesign its says that findMapNo(...).map.clearLayers is not a function...

Comment: @StackSlave yes. it should be like that... since they have same zoom, when i click the data for the second layer, it should remove the previous layer and add the second layer

Comment: Nope, that's the same Object with the same properties.

Comment: @StackSlave i dont get it.. im sorry im new to leaflet...

Comment: Sorry my mistake `clearLayers()` can only called on layergroups or featuregroups.

Comment: @StackSlave means that you call `findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(marker);` and 2 lines later you call `findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(marker);` with the same marker object

Comment: @FalkeDesign you mean that the marker that i remove and the marker that i add has same object, thats why its not removing?

Comment: @FalkeDesign the groupMarker in `L.marker(latLng, {icon: customIcon}).bindTooltip(tooltp).addTo(groupMarker)` is a layerGroup.

Comment: @FalkeDesign i already tried `clearLayers()` but not `map.clearLayers()`, instead i tried `groupMarker.clearLayers(findMapNo(no).map)`. i put it inside the **if** of `hasLayer()` but is just show 1 marker with 1 tooltip and icon...

Comment: if you want to clear the groupMarker you have to call `groupMarker.clearLayers()`
Yeah the marker object that you create with `marker = L.marker(latLng, {icon: customIcon}).bindTooltip(tooltp).addTo(groupMarker);` never changing